# use variable inside src attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, attributes, src, jquery-lazyload

I use B-Lazy plugin (http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/) on a website projet. I would like to load different image in terms of windows width :

If window width < 420px, the plugin accepts to load an img whose 'data-src' is remplace by 'data-src-small'.

So, I would like to get the data-src image url and add to the end '-228x170' just before '.jpg' like that :

`<img data-src="img-name.jpg" >`
become 
`<img data-src-small="img-name-228x170.jpg" >`

here my code : 
`

```
$('img').addClass('b-lazy');

$("img.b-lazy").each(function() {       

         $(this).attr("data-src",$(this).attr("src"));
         $(this).attr('src','data:trans.gif');

        var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $(this).attr('src', 'src + -228x170.jpg' ); //here my mistake

 });
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you go, just change where the quote is, and remove the initial extension:

```
var src = $(this).attr('data-src').replace('.jpg', '');
$(this).attr('src', src + '-228x170.jpg' );
```

Per question in comments:

```
var src = $(this).attr('data-src').replace('.jpg', '');
var specialChars = ('fooo'); //this can be set dynamically

$(this).attr('src', src + '-228' + specialChars  + '.jpg' );
```

HTH,
-Ted

Comment: And, if I would like to not specify the height value 'x170' ? is it possible to write something like `(this).attr('src', src + '-228????.jpg' );`with four caracters unspecified before `.jpg` ?

Comment: as it is a string, you can put whatever you need to there,

Comment: Thanks @Ted but I don't know how to write `-228 + (4 caracters who are not always the same) + .jpg`

Comment: I added an example to the answer. Is that what you has in mind?

Comment: Yes thanks for the exemple. In fact, I would like to replace `('fooo')` dynamically has you say, by '4 caracters' who would be change in differents cases. exemple : `src + -228 + x356 + .jpg` or `src + -228 + x657 + .jpg` or.... etc.